# How do I find which processes are using files on an external volumes? (Montarey)

Tags: macos

Activity Monitor doesn't say which file path the process name is.

Nor does it offer any way that I know of to list files that are open on a specific volume.

Is there a way / third party tool / terminal command to list the active files that are open/in use on external volumes?

Is there a way to monitor disk activity PER DISK?

Comment: Have you tried typing `ls -R ` and then dragging the external volume in Terminal? It should list all the files in the volume

Comment: Activity Monitor does show the path under the "Info > Open Files and Ports" option. `lsof` is a list of open files, so `sudo lsof /Volumes/SomeVolume` will list the open ones on that volume. "What's Keeping Me" would be a 3ʳᵈ party tool for it.

Comment: In addition to `lsof` recommended by @Redarm, try running   The command `awk '/\/Volumes\/External_Mount/ {print}' <<< $(ps -e)`. That should give you a list of processes attached to files on the mount point.  Note:  in `awk`, the search pattern is between slashes (`/search string/`). Since a path has  slashes, you must escape them by putting a backslash before the slash in the path: `/Volumes/` = `\/Volumes\/`